# Check if a data sheet exists in R

Tags: r, excel, shiny

I have a shiny application in which the user can upload a file. Depending on if this file has 1 or 2 datasheets the functionality should be different. 
I import a datasheet with read.xlsx, where data_in is the path:

```
data <-read.xlsx(data_in,1,1,colNames=TRUE)
```

So this is the first sheet of the file. The second sheet can be imported in the same way of course. But if it does not have a second sheet, I want it to handle that by for instance pasting a warning, or continuing in a different way.

So, how to determine whether a second sheet exists in the data file?

Appreciate your help!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answers above nicely point out solutions to your specific problem. I just want to add a general solution for such issues: you could take a look at `tryCatch()`.
This allows you to define what should happen if an error or warning ocurred in your code.

```
result <- tryCatch({
        # The code you want run
    }, warning = function(war) {
        # Is executed if warning encountered
    }, error = function(err) {
        # Is executed if error encountered
    })
```

In your example, you could try to read in the second sheet and define what should happen if this throws an error.

Comment: I actually also like this one yes. The idea of going on from an error was not known for me, so I try to avoid it. Instead, I think this solves the problem more to the core. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

There is a method **existsSheet** to check the existence of sheets in excel files in **XLConnect** package.

You can try following:

```
# mtcars xlsx file from demoFiles subfolder of package XLConnect
demoExcelFile <- system.file("demoFiles/mtcars.xlsx", package = "XLConnect")

# Load workbook
wb <- loadWorkbook(demoExcelFile)

# Check for existence of a worksheet called 'mtcars'
existsSheet(wb, "mtcars")
```

Please refer [this](http://artax.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/r-help/library/XLConnect/html/existsSheet-methods.html) for more details:

Comment: Thanks @Nishu Tayal for the answer. It is a usefull method but for this case not the best I think because you have to know the name of the worksheet. I do not define how the user should call his worksheets and I do not intend on doing so as this can only lead to more errors etc.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the `excel_sheets` function of the [`readxl`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/readxl/index.html) package in order to "List all sheets in an excel spreadsheet".

```
library(readxl)
excel_sheets("path/to/excel/file")
```

From the Docs:

```
# To load all sheets in a workbook, use lapply
path <- system.file("extdata/datasets.xls", package = "readxl")
lapply(excel_sheets(path), read_excel, path = path)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
It worked for me with openxlsx

nfile <- "D:\\Temp\\NCLWKBOM.xlsx"
x <- ""
y<- ""

# check for file existance
if (file.exists(nfile)) {
  wb <- loadWorkbook(nfile)

#check sheet existance name(wb) gives name of sheet in wb
for (x in names(wb)){
    if (x == "NCLBOM") {
      y <- TRUE
    }
  }
  if (y != TRUE) {
    addWorksheet(wb, "NCLBOM")
  }

}else {
  wb <- createWorkbook()
  addWorksheet(wb, "NCLBOM")
}
```